# Вызов js методов из .net приложения

Tags: javascript, java, c#, .net, webbrowser

Имеется основной веб проект написанный на java и .net приложение на winforms. Внутри desktop приложения с помощью geckofx открывается ссылка на модуль основного проекта. Подскажите какие нибудь варианты того, как можно передавать данные из front-а основного проекта в десктоп? Возможно как  то получится вызывать js методы из него?

Comment: Для вызова js-а можете использовать `InvokeScript`: `object res = webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("method", args);` Только не забудьте о `WebBrowser.IsScriptEnabled`

Comment: Мне нужно из js-a вызывать методы на десктопном приложении, это возможно как то?